# Autolayout strange behaviour on Ipad

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

collection view getting right size with auto layout but view size on collection view is not working properly view on collection view taking size from storyboard design. its depend what you setting size in storyboard design. its working perfectly in Iphone but not working in Ipad. i tried to setting size in size for item at section but its not working.
dropbox link of project is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/imcbeoqz9h3y4kb/AAAOwg9OEj3wvMMH6EhZ4B0Ba?dl=0).

**[image: code is:-]**

```
let isPad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
import UIKit

class AchivementVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var clcAchivement:UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func btnBackClick(sender:UIButton)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
extension AchivementVC:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "achiveCell", for: indexPath) as! AchiveClcCell
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print(collectionView.frame)
        if(isPad)
        {
             return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.5)-30, height: (collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.45)-30)
        }
        else
        {
            return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.5)-10, height: (collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.45)-10)
        }

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if(isPad)
        {
            return 30
        }
        else
        {
            return 10
        }
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if(isPad)
        {
            return 30
        }
        else
        {
            return 10
        }
    }


}
class AchiveClcCell:UICollectionViewCell
{


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write a [mcve] and copy it into your question body, and maybe add some screenshots of the problem?

Comment: i am showing complete demo please see project on dropbox

Answer (score 0):

You should call `super.layoutSubviews()` when you override `layoutSubviews`